# More brief conditions in C

Tags: c, if-statement

So, here is my problem:
I have a squared matrix that represent a neighborhood with an epidemic, every cell in the matrix represents a house.  There are three different situations for a house S is for sick, H for healed, C for contagious. I recive a number of days and then I change the initial situation for the neighborhood and I change the neighborhood in every day following the upcoming rules:

- If the house is 'H' that its upper/below/left/right neighbor is 'C' it turns into a 'C' house (not in diagonal).
- If the house is 'C' and has at least two 'C' neighbors turns into an 'S' house (in this situation the neighbors are upper/below/left/right/diagonals, here we have 8 different options).
- If the house is 'S' then it turns into a 'H' house.

It isn't a tough question but my question is that if I can write a more brief conditions for the edge cases.

This is a function that checks the edge situations when the house is 'C':

```
void limit_C(char **neigh, int i, int j, int d, char **help)
{
    int counter = 0;

    if ((i == 0) && (j == 0))
   {
       if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
       {counter++;}
           
          if(help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
           if(counter >= 2)
           {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
       
   }
   else if ((i == d - 1) && (j == d - 1))
   {
         if(help[i - 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
       
         if(help[i][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
         {counter++;}
       
         if(help[i - 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
       
       if(counter >= 2)
            {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
   }
       
   else if ((i == d - 1) && (j == 0))
   {
          if(help[i - 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i - 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
       if(counter >= 2)
            {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
   }
   else if ((i == 0) && (j == d - 1))
   {
          if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
       if(counter >= 2)
            {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
       
   }
   
  else if((i == 0) && (j != 0))
   {
          if(help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
           
          if(help[i][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
       if(counter >= 2)
       {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
       
   }
   
   else if ((i != 0) && (j == 0))
   {
          if(help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i - 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i - 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
       
          if(help[i + 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
          {counter++;}
      
       if(counter >= 2)
       {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
       
   }
    else if((i == d - 1) && (j != d - 1))
    {
        if(help[i - 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i - 1][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i - 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(counter >= 2)
        {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
        
        
    }
    
    else if((i != d - 1) && (j == d - 1))
    {
        if(help[i - 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i - 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(help[i + 1][j - 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
        {counter++;}
        
        if(counter >= 2)
        {neigh[i][j] = SICK;}
        
    }
}
```

so is there a briefer way to write the same code?

Comment: It's going to be messy no matter what you do. Basically what I would change would be the direct equality or non-equality operations to larger-than or less-than `>` and `<` against the limits instead. And put the limits checks in the actual `CONTAGIOUS` checks. Then you don't need the extra nesting, and you could to only one `counter >= 2` check.

Comment: I don't understand the following sentence in the question: `"If the house is 'H' that its upper/below/left/right neighbor is 'C' it turns into a 'C' house (not in diagonal)."` Do you maybe mean "and" instead of "that"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of code like:

```
   if(help[i + 1][j] == CONTAGIOUS)
   {counter++;}
```

I would introduce a helper function to do the compare. Something like:

```
int is_C(char **neigh, int i, int j, int d)
{
    if (i < 0) return 0;
    if (i >= d) return 0;
    if (j < 0) return 0;
    if (j >= d) return 0;
    return neigh[i][j] == CONTAGIOUS;
}
```

With that helper function in place you don't need to worry about edge case. Just check all 8 neighbor.

```
int count_C(char **neigh, int i, int j, int d)
{
    int cnt = 0;
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i-1, j-1, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i-1, j, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i-1, j+1, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i, j-1, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i, j+1, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i+1, j-1, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i+1, j, d);
    cnt += is_C(neigh, i+1, j+1, d);
    return cnt;
}
```

Then you have simple code like:

```
for (int i = 0; i < d; ++i)
{ 
    for (int j = 0; j < d; ++j)
    { 
        if (neigh[i][j] == CONTAGIOUS && count_C(neigh, i, j, d) >= 2)
        {
            neigh[i][j] = SICK;  // or tmp_neigh[i][j] = SICK; See note
        }
     }
}
```

*note:* It could be that the rules for "the game" requires a temporary matrix to hold the new state during updates.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you could do is use for-loops to iterate over each of the possible neighbor-positions to check, rather than explicitly implementing each neighbor's check with separate code.  Something like this (I realize my example's logic isn't the same as your program's logic, this is just to give the general idea):

```
void limit_C(char **neigh, int i, int j, int d, char **help)
{
   int counter = 0;
   for (int di=-1; di<=1; di++)
   {
      for (int dj=-1; dj<=1; dj++)
      {
         if ((di==0)&&(dj==0)) continue;  // no point checking a house against itself!

         const int neighborX = (i+di);
         const int neighborY = (i+dj);

         // avoid checking grid-positions that aren't valid
         if ((neighborX < 0)||(neighborX >= d)) continue;
         if ((neighborY < 0)||(neighborY >= d)) continue;

         if (help[neighborX][neighborY] == 'C') counter++;
      }
   }
   if (counter >= 2) neigh[i][j] = SICK;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You could make loops that starts at `[i-1][j-1]` and goes to `[i+1][j+1]` but excludes the edges.

Example:

```c
void limit_C(char **neigh, int i, int j, int d, char** help) {
    int counter = 0;
    int ys = i + (i > 0 ? -1 : 0);
    int xs = j + (j > 0 ? -1 : 0);
    int ye = i + (i < d - 1 ? 1 : 0);
    int xe = j + (j < d - 1 ? 1 : 0);

    for (int y = ys; y <= ye; ++y) {
        for (int x = xs; x <= xe; ++x) {
            if(y == i && x == j) continue;
            if (help[y][x] == CONTAGIOUS) counter++;
        }
    }
    if (counter >= 2) neigh[i][j] = SICK;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

To summarize the question: how do we gracefully handle situations at the edges of the grid, when we want to check neighbors?

**One option** is to just check the bounds for each condition, e.g.:

```
if(j + 1 < d && help[i][j + 1] == CONTAGIOUS)
```

Because the `&&` operator is [short-circuiting](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Short-circuit_evaluation), there will be no access to your matrix if the first part of the condition.

**Another option** is to extend your matrix by one in each direction -- so if your input is `[d][d]`, you allocate `[d+2][d+2]`. Make sure to initialize the edges to a good default (what you want "missing" neighbors to be considered, maybe `HEALED`?).

Then just call your update function for the "real" positions -- note how the indices are shifted up one step (starting at 1, and going up to and *including* `d`).

```
for (int i=1; i<=d; ++i) {
    for (int j=1; j<=d; ++j) {
        limit_C(neigh, i, j, d, help)
    }
}
```

This way, your update function doesn't need to check the bounds at all, since `i` and `j` will never be less than 1 (so `i-1` will never be less than 0), and never larger than `d` (so `i+1` will be less than `d+2`, which is the actual size of the matrix). So you're free to just do:

```
if (help[i][j+1] == CONTAGIOUS)
```

Remember that with this option, you need to keep in mind that the indices are shifted. For example, when outputting the results.